# Difference between the use of double quote and quotes in python

Tags: python

Is there any difference between the use of double quotes to single quotes in Python?

```
"A string with double quotes"
'A string with single quotes'
```

Are they identical? Are there differences in how python interprets these strings?

Comment: Not exactly the same question, but the answer to both is in that thread.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that question, whatsoever. The fact that the answer to this question is incorporated in that question does **NOT** make it a dupe. Please nominate this question for reopening and join me in the fight against overzealous moderation.

Answer (score 26):

Short answer: almost no difference except stylistically.
Short blurb: If you don't want to escape the quote characters inside your string, use the other type. eg:

```
string1 = "He turned to me and said, \"Hello there\""
```

would be slightly more unsightly than saying

```
string2 = 'He turned to me and said, "Hello there"'
```

The same applies to single quotes/apostrophes.

Answer (score 4):

Not generally, you just have to be consistent within a given statement.  E.g., don't do "foo'

For further reading, see [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals).

Answer (score 1):

Double quotes look distinctive. Single quotes look like single ticks. Apart from that ...