# Difference between using ' and "?

Tags: python, quotes

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Difference between the use of double quote and quotes in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628657/difference-between-the-use-of-double-quote-and-quotes-in-python)
>   [Single quotes vs. double quotes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56011/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-python)

So I am now learning python, and was creating a function. What is the difference between using ' and ". I will create a sample function below to exemplify my question.

```
def question(variable):
    print variable
```

now what is the difference between calling

```
question("hello")
```

and

```
question('hello')
```

they both print hello, but why can I use both? Is it just because python is flexible? I was confused because ' is usually used for chars where as " is for strings for java right?

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56011/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-python

Comment: If voting to close as a duplicate, please vote to close on the question linked by carl and not the original possible duplicate (which is itself just a "duplicate").

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Both are equal and what you use is entirely your preference.

As far as the `char` vs `string` thing is concerned, refer to the `Zen of Python`, ([PEP 20](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) or `import this`)

```
Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
```

A string of length 1 is not special enough to have a dedicated `char` type.

Note that you can do:

```
>>> print 'Double" quote inside single'
Double" quote inside single
>>> print "Single' quote inside double"
Single' quote inside double
```

Comment: im not a smart man, but i know not to question a guy with roughly 200x my reputation score. having said that, does this remain true if you are going between languages (e.g. into bash?)?

Answer (score 17):

" is useful when you have ' into the string and vice versa

Answer (score 6):

Python does not have that restriction of single quotes for chars and double quotes for strings.

As you can see here the grammar explicitly allows both for strings.

http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals